# Should I group this dataset for Random Forest model?

Tags: random-forest

I would like to make a model to predict grid id using two sensors (s1 and s2) features. A device emits a signal (e.g., WiFi) and sensors detect the signals. Each sensors record the RSSI (strength of signal) and freq (detection frequency).

```
   grid_id    s1_RSSI s1_freq s2_RSSI s2_freq
0  grid_01       100     10       5      5
1  grid_01       200     20       3      3
2  grid_02       100     10      200    20
3  grid_02       30      5       100    10
```

In above table, it assumed that s1 sensor is near grid_01. If a device is in grid_01, there is higher RSSI and freq of s1 sensor rather than s2 sensor.

If I make a randomforest model, below is the simple code.

```
fp.rf <- randomForest(grid_id ~ ., ntree = 500, data = fp, importance=TRUE)
```

However, I think that `s1_RSSI` and `s1_freq` should be grouped separately because these two variables would be highly correlated rather than `s2_RSSI` and `s2_freq`.

In real datasets, there are more sensors (s1 to s6) and more parameters (RSSI, freq, ...).

Here is my questions:

1) The term 'group' is right to apply my model?

2) Do I need to group the variables for my model?